# C# - datagridview encoding utf-8

Tags: c#, c, datagridview

I have problem with datagridview encoding utf-8. There are Georgian letters shown as ????? in the picture, and here is link: http://postimg.org/image/63o1evn77/
Thank you beforehand.

Comment: DataGridView itself doesn't have any encoding associated with it. The problem must be located in the value behind. Please provide more information.

Comment: Another idea would be, that the default font of your operating system don't support the letters. Tahoma is the default system font of Windows XP, on Vista, Windows 7 it is Segoe UI. Check it.